# Is there any way I can save the plot as .jpg

Tags: python-3.x

I use plt.plot() to plot a figure and want to save it as .jpg. However, I can only manage to use plt.savefig() to save it as .png. Is there any way I can save the plot as .jpg? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not notice that before. It helps a lot!